# How can I sort in Google Sheets by cells containing section (or version) numbers?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm indexing a document with sections and sub-sections. I want to have one column representing the section-number and be able to sort by this column. However when the sub-section gets higher than 10, the sort no longer works.

This is the order I want...

```
1-1
1-2
1-10
2-1
```

Of course when we know this represents sections and sub-sections (or for example major and minor version numbers) that 1-10 is higher than 1-2, but of course both alphabetical and numerical sorting produces this order:

```
1-1
1-10
1-2
2-1
```

Is there a way to use numeric string sort (like `-V` to `sort`) in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 1):

The following sorts a range (like A1:A7) of such strings:

```
=array_constrain(sort({A1:A7, value(regexextract(A1:A7, "^\d+")), value(regexextract(A1:A7, "\d+$"))}, 2, true, 3, true), 10000000, 1)
```

Same formula with  linebreaks for readability:

```
=array_constrain(
   sort(
     {
       A1:A7, 
       value(regexextract(A1:A7, "^\d+")), 
       value(regexextract(A1:A7, "\d+$"))
     }, 
   2, true, 3, true), 
 10000000, 1)
```

Given n rows, this creates a rectangular array with three columns, where the 2nd and 3rd columns are numbers extracted from the string. The sort command sorts first by 2nd, then by 3rd. Finally, `array_constrain` outputs only the first column of the sorted array.

Answer (score 0):

What could be useful is instead of using

```
1-1
1-2
...
1-10
```

you can use as much "digits" as your largest number; like this:

```
1-01
1-02
...
1-99
```

In this case my largest number will be 99.

Comment: And a month later, you need 100 and 101. Then what?

Comment: So far, I've been trying several options and still don`t succeed. So, until now, the best solution I can to figure it out is to add one more digit. i.e. 1-001